# Api request returns 415 but it doesnt have media files

Tags: flutter, api, dart

I try to add an address to a server with this API, but the problem is it's returning an Error 415 message in the images, but I don't send any media files, I just send a JSON map like shown in the images as well.

**although it works in the postman it returns this error in the emulator.**

this is the function of the API request

```
  Future addAddress(Placemark placemark) async {
try {
  String token = DataSaver.getData(tokenKey);

  Uri uri = Uri.parse("$url$usersTag/$uid$addressTag");
  var response = await http
      .post(
    uri,
    headers: <String, String>{
      'userId': uid,
      "Authorization": "Bearer $token",
    },
    body: json.encode(AddressCredintials.fromPlacemark(placemark)),
  )
      .timeout(timeoutDuration, onTimeout: () {
    log("request TimeOut");
    return http.Response('Error', 408);
  });

  print(response.body.toString());
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    log("address added");
  } else {
    print(response.statusCode);
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
} }
```

this is the class I am using.

```
class AddressCredintials {
  String govID;
  String cityID;
  String? villageID;
  String street;
  String? building;
  String? apartment;

  AddressCredintials(
      {this.apartment,
      this.building,
      required this.street,
      required this.cityID,
      required this.govID,
      this.villageID});

  factory AddressCredintials.fromPlacemark(Placemark placemark) {
    return AddressCredintials(
        street: placemark.street,
        cityID: placemark.city.id,
        govID: placemark.government.id,
        apartment: placemark.apartment,
        building: placemark.building,
        villageID: placemark.village != null ? placemark.village!.id : null);
  }

  Map toJson() {
    return {
      "governorateId": govID,
      "cityId": cityID,
      "areaId": villageID,
      "street": street,
      "buildingNo": building,
      "appartmentNo": apartment
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the header this value
`"content-type": "application/json"`

and in case your response is also a json add this
`"accept": "application/json"`

Comment: I don't get any response and when I put 'content-type": "application/json' 
it turns it to 406 status code

Comment: actually it turns out this worked but there was a bug in the API itself, thanks a lot.